# Can one's body temperature affect the quality of his/her sleep?

Tags: sleep, body-temperature, contributing-factors

If so, how does it influence our sleep?  And what can we do to improve the quality of sleep in regards to adjusting our body temperature?

Comment: Do you mean actual body temperature (more or less than 37°C) or environment temperature?

Comment: @YviDe I suppose both are significant, so answers on either can be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Body temperature [drops at night](http://www.sleepdex.org/thermoregulation.htm) almost 2 degrees fahrenheit.

Cranial cooling has been showing to [lead to deeper sleep and help insomniacs](https://xenophilius.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/cant-sleep-cooling-your-brain-may-be-a-natural-and-effective-treatment-for-insomnia/).

Higher body temperatures during sleep are [associated with depression](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9209729).

As a physician, I have a seen previous studies suggesting that taking a lukewarm shower before sleeping has been shown to help people get to sleep faster [reference needed].

Anecdotally, I have patients who report that walking around without socks on the floor until their feet feel cold also report falling asleep faster.

Comment: So lower body tempature = better sleep?

Comment: Only to an extent. Too low of a temperature and people are unable to sleep.